# How to create a view based on a company in leads

Tags: reporting, view

I have to create a new view in leads based on a single company.How to achieve i don't have any idea regarding this because company contains what to match for this list to get all related companies list

Comment: Do you want one listview for every company? Or one listview for a specific company?

Comment: Is it possible one list view for every company.Means is there any way to do so @Sebastian Kessel.

Comment: Yes, but it is VERY difficult, You'd need to create a trigger on lead, and create a new listview (using the metadata API) every time a new company is detected. Not something I'd recommend doing.

Comment: thanks actually my problem is i created record type for lead and in our company research team is there.When they try to assign leads to a particular company.They are try to mass edit leads at a time.means they didn't get options to edit.they are try to edit manually..@Sebastian Kessel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it i have created a view contains with company contains and forgot to mention record type there so now it's working fine in my production.So now i can get all related company with locations and everything.